# SpriteKit: Obtain exclusive lock on Scene Children

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin, sprite-kit

I'm working on an iOS game that uses SpriteKit.
The levels are dynamically generated during game play, which I'm trying to perform in a separate thread.

When new objects in the level are about to become visible on the screen, they are added to the Scene's children collection, using `scene.AddChild()`.
Objects that have moved off-screen are removed from the Scene's children collection, using `scene.RemoveChild()`.

The problem is that the Children array is also being accessed by another thread (one that I have no control over).
That results in an exception being thrown, because the scene.Children array is being mutated by multiple threads:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  
Name: NSGenericException 
Reason: *** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x15e5bac0> was mutated while being enumerated.
at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
```

***Does anyone know a way of locking the Scene's Children collection or to determine whether a different thread is already locking it?***

I might want to add that the children are not directly added to the Scene, but rather to one object in the scene.
So there is a 'Level Layer' node that is continuously updated with new level objects.
If I take the logic outside of the separate thread, it works perfectly fine, but will make the game jittery every time a new section of the level is generated (hence the separate thread).

Comment: can't you just create the array on a separate thread, and then addChild the nodes in the array on the main thread? I doubt it will be possible to avoid these synchronization issues since you do not have access to the Sprite Kit source code.

Comment: ^ I'd have to say @LearnCocos2D, suggestion is probably the best approach. I suppose you could make a Hard copy of the array for the thread and then the thread is finished, sync it with the main thread's array. Not sure how well that would work but it should stop the crashing.

Comment: It's the adding of children that is the performance-consuming part. I've tried moving only level generation into a separate that (which works fine), but I still get jitters when the children are actually added if I do that in the main thread. But you pointed me in the right direction, will look into optimizing the way of adding children. Probably by setting a maximum number of children that may be added within one update iteration.

Comment: You might be able to address this situation by adding more hierarchy to your node tree: don't work directly with the level layer's children on your secondary thread, but instead break it into chunks. In other words—since it sounds like you're trying to do something like repopulate offscreen parts of a tile map—make each of your LevelNode's children be a secondary container holding about a screen's worth of tiles. On a background thread you can fill in a ScreenNode with tiles, then once that's done add it to the LevelNode on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks Rickster, but I'm already doing that. There is a considerate level of hiearchy: Scene -> World -> LevelObjectLayer -> Platforms -> Tiles. I'm now implementing LevelObjectLayer child adding to work with a threshold so there is a max N child adds per Update iteration. That will probably be sufficient

Comment: ..and distributing the child adds over multiple Update iterations has done the job. Thanks for the help!